# Installing simplenote.vim for vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I copied simplenote.vim to my `~/.vim/plugin` directory and added the login variables to the `.vimrc`.  When I launch vim, it will autocomplete `:Simplenote`.

But when I add an argument and execute I get the error

```
E117: Unknown function: simplenote#SimpleNote
```

I know I have python installed on MacVim because `:python` asks for an argument.

Comment: figured it out.  from the simplnote.vim archive, install what is in the autoload/ to your .vim/autoload/  and install the file in plugin/ to your /.vim/plugin/.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the entire archive; just the `plugin/` contents won't suffice. Since Vim 7, the *autoload* mechanism allows plugins to lazy-load much of their functionality on first use, reducing Vim startup time and memory footprint.

Many users prefer a plugin manager like *Vundle* or *Pathogen*; it makes installing and updating plugins easier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need both files installed. Just saw that I didn't update the installation notes in the README when I switched to autoload. Sorry about that. I'm going to update the instructions there.